# Auto Clicker for AHK that clicks and holds down control, only while i press F9

Tags: automation, autohotkey

I need a script in AHK that auto-clicks and holds down the control key at the same time for a software that I am using. I would love to be able to bind that action to like F9

I have found scripts that auto click, but they are toggles and I don't know how to add the function of holding down control at the same time.

Comment: Welcome to SO. To add the functionality of holding down control, you would need to put `Send , {ctrl down}` within the toggle portion of the code. You'd need a `Send , {ctrl up}` as well to release it when you're finished. It would be helpful if you post the code that you want the functionality added to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit more compact. Note that this is also setup for using ctrl+F9 because once control is held down, F9 won't turn off the autoclicking since it thinks you're pressing ctrl+F9. It will click wherever your mouse is, but you can add coordinates if you want to click in a specific location. I put a sleep in there for 50ms, but modify to suit your needs.

```
f9::
^f9::
Send , % ( bT := !bT ) ? "{ctrl down}" : ""
While( bT )
{
    Click ; Clicks wherever your mouse is. Add coordinates if you need a specific pos.
    Sleep , 50
}
Send , {ctrl up}
Return
```

Answer (score 0):

```
q::
auto = true
send, {CONTROL DOWN}
while(auto){
    mouseclick, left, "X-Cord","Y-Cord"
    if GetKeyState(q)
      auto =true    
}
send, {CONTROL UP}
return
```

As you cant run 2 commands at the literal same time this should work.
If you wanted to be more precise depending on what your using it for,
this would be better:

```
q::
x := ;place your desired coordinates in these two variables.
y :=
f1::
 {
     mousegetpos, start_x, start_y
     auto = true
     send, {CONTROL DOWN}
     while(auto){
       mouseclick, left, %x%, %y%, 1, 0
       if GetKeyState(q)
         auto =true 
    }
    send, {CONTROL UP}
    mousemove, %start_x%, %start_y%, 0
 }
return
```

This will get your cursor position, move cursor to point as fast as possible, hold control down, left click, let go of control, return to original position.

> Use 'q' to start and terminate